# Twitter: Accessing home timeline with key and secret

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a list of other users' access_token_key and access_token_key_secret. Is it possible to get their home timeline tweets with only these information?

Do I need my own consumer key and consumer secret? I followed this https://python-twitter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html but get 'Could not authenticate you'

Answer (score 0):

The access token key and access token key secret are returned by a particular twitter aplication that's different to the one you could create. A connection created with those tokens and your own application consumer key and consumer secret values wont work because those tokens were returned by another app